# How can I add a date for each days with laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am working on the laravel project, which I have to show the availability of each doctor for all the week, so I just add the name of the day and the availability ( start time, end time ), but I couldn't match the date with every day with the day.

This is the controller :

```php
public function rdv( $ID)
{
    $calendar  = collect([]);
    $model=doc::findOrFail($ID);
//Monday
    $mondayMorningStart    = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de[0]) ; //Get Timestamp
    $mondayMorningEnd = strtotime($model->Lun_mat_de[1]);
    $mondayMidiStart = strtotime($model->Lun_apres_a[0]);
    $mondayMidiEnd      = strtotime($model->Lun_apres_a[1]); //Get Timestamp
    $calendar->monday  = getAvailabilityCalendar($mondayMorningStart, $mondayMorningEnd, $mondayMidiStart, $mondayMidiEnd);
//Tuesday
..
return view ('/rendezvous',['go'=> $model],['calendar'=>$calendar] );

function getAvailabilityCalendar($morningStart, $morningEnd, $eveningStart, $eveningEnd) 
{
  $calendar = collect([]);

  /**
   * Morning
   */
  $start = $morningStart;
   $end = $morningEnd;
   while($start < $end ) {
     $calendar->push($start);
     $start = strtotime('+1 hour', $start);
   }
   /**
    * Evenning
    */
   $start = $eveningStart;
   $end = $eveningEnd;
   while($start < $end ) {
     $calendar->push($start);
     $start = strtotime('+1 hour', $start);
   }
   $calendar->transform(function($item) {
     return date('G:i', $item);
   }); 
   return $calendar;
}
```

This is the view for the calendar:

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" id="prev"> <  </button>
<div id="date" style="height:100px; width:300px; font-size:17px">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" id="next"> > </button>

</div>

<h2>Lun</h2>
@foreach($calendar->monday as $ja)
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> {{$ja}} </button> </br>
@endforeach

</div>

<div class="col">
  <h2>Mar</h2>
  @foreach($calendar->tuesday as $ja)
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> {{$ja}} </button> </br>
  @endforeach
</div>

<div class="col">
  <h2>Mer</h2>
  @foreach($calendar->wednesday as $ja)
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> {{$ja}} </button> </br>
  @endforeach
</div>

<div class="col">
  <h2>Jeu</h2>
  @foreach($calendar->thursday as $ja)
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> {{$ja}} </button> </br>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share your HTML or JS code?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur okay i will add this in my post

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur can you please check again my post

Comment: what is the contain or return of `$model=doc::findOrFail($ID)` ?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur showing the doctor

Comment: how to you say the doctor is available ? you have to put such condition !

Comment: the  doctor has a form witch he put his avaibility